# Unable to test controller using Action.async

Tags: scala, playframework, specs2, playframework-2.2

I'm trying to test controller, which is using new `Action.async`. Following [documentation](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ScalaTest) I have excluded part under controller I want to test to separate trait with type reference:

```
trait UserController { this: Controller =>
  def index() = Action { /* snip */ }
  def register() = Action.async(parse.json) { request => /* snip */ }
}
```

Documentation states that I'm supposed to test it as:

```
object UsersControllerSpec extends PlaySpecification with Results {
  class TestController() extends Controller with UserController
    "index action" should {
      "should be valid" in {
        val controller = new TestController()
        val result: Future[SimpleResult] = controller.index().apply(FakeRequest())
        /* assertions */
      }
    }
  }
}
```

For `index()` method it works perfectly, unfortunately I'm not able to do the same with `register()`, as applying FakeRequest on it returns instance of `Iteratee[Array[Byte], SimpleResult]`. I've noticed it has `run()` method that returns `Future[SimpleResult]` but no matter how I build `FakeRequest` it returns with `400` without any content or headers. Seems to me like content of `FakeRequest` is disregarded at all. Am I supposed to feed request body to iteratee somehow and then run it? I couldn't find any example how could I do that.

Comment: Any luck with this? It's driving me crazy!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For me works this:

```
import concurrent._
import play.api.libs.json._
import play.api.mvc.{SimpleResult, Results, Controller, Action}
import play.api.test._
import ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

trait UserController {
  this: Controller =>
  def index() = Action {
    Ok("index")
  }

  def register() = Action.async(parse.json) {
    request =>
      future(Ok("register: " + request.body))
  }
}

object UsersControllerSpec extends PlaySpecification with Results {

  class TestController() extends Controller with UserController

  "register action" should {
    "should be valid" in {
      val controller = new TestController()
      val request = FakeRequest().withBody(Json.obj("a" -> JsString("A"), "b" -> JsString("B")))
      val result: Future[SimpleResult] = controller.register()(request)
      /* assertions */
      contentAsString(result) === """register: {"a":"A","b":"B"}"""
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm getting similar problems for my secured actions, is there a similar solution? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26303705/secured-trait-causing-spec2-unit-test-compilation-errors

Comment: A gotcha on this, and further to @tjdett's comments, is that `withJsonBody` returns a `FakeRequest[AnyContentAsJson]`, not `FakeRequest[JsValue]`. So don't use `withJsonBody`, use `withBody`.

Answer (score 10):

This problem arises because `play.api.mvc.Action[A]` contains these two apply methods:

```
// What you're hoping for
def apply(request: Request[A]): Future[Result]

// What actually gets called
def apply(rh: RequestHeader): Iteratee[Array[Byte], Result]
```

This arises because `Request[A] extends RequestHeader`, and the `A` in this case makes all the difference. If it's not the right type, you'll end up calling the wrong `apply`.

When you use `ActionBuilder` with a `BodyParser[A]`, you create an `Action[A]`. As a result, you'll need a `Request[A]` to test. `parse.json` returns a `BodyParser[JsValue]`, so you need a `Request[JsValue]`.

```
// In FakeRequest object
def apply(): FakeRequest[AnyContentAsEmpty.type]
```

`FakeRequest()` doesn't get you the type you need. Fortunately:

```
// In FakeRequest class
def withBody[B](body: B): FakeRequest[B]
```

So, start writing your test by using a placeholder for the body:

```
  "should be valid" in {
    val controller = new TestController()
    val body: JsValue = ??? // Change this once your test compiles

    // Could do these lines together, but this shows type signatures
    val request: Request[JsValue] = FakeRequest().withBody(body)
    val result: Future[Result] = controller.index().apply(request)

    /* assertions */
  }
```